# Run Java Application

Tags: java

I just got an application from our client for reference. It looks like a java application however not sure, since i am .Net developer. Here is the structure of the application:

1. app
2. components
3. data
4. framework
5. libs
6. META-INF
7. plugin
8. resources
9. storeserv
10. WEB-INF

and then some html ,javascript files at the root.

I just want to run this application on the browser for now.

Can anyone please confirm if this is java application? If yes, please let me know how to launch the same on the browser (I am not sure if this is published or the code itself). I could not find any class, jar files anywhere in this app.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: looks like an app for an java application server like tomcat to me

Comment: It looks like a web application, i.e. something you'll run with a JEE server such as Glassfish (or possibly a servlet container/JEE "Web Profile" server such as Tomcat). It will almost certainly *not* run in a browser ('though you will need a browser to access it).

Comment: where have you found this one? :) If you could find at least one java class you could say it's partly java application :)

Comment: It may be java app with server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it looks like a Java web application.

To run it : Install Apache [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi). Note the installation port in your installation.

Inside the `META-INF` folder (of your client files) you will probably find a `context.xml` file. Open it in a text editor and note the path. It will be something like `<context path="/appname">`

Then place all the files in `$CATALINA_HOME/webapps/appname` , where `$CATALINA_HOME` stands for the installation directory of the Tomcat Server.

Then restart your server(this might not even be necessary).

Access the application at URL: `http://localhost:port/appname`

Enjoy

Comment: I cannot find any context.xml inside META-INF. However there is a manifest.mf file avilable in it.

Comment: ok, try creating a dir in catalina_home ex `test` and put all files there. Then try to access `localhost:port/test`

Answer (score 2):

The given project is a WEB-application for Java.

To run it you need a Web Application container (like Tomcat or Jetty) and deploy it to this Web Application container. Then you can browse the application.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Any tutorial where you can point me for the same?

Comment: This is not so easy but [here](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/GettingStarted) is a collection of links for tomcat for this.

Answer (score 1):

In order to be executed, a web application must be deployed on a servlet container(Tomcat, Jetty etc.). This is true even during development. I will describe using [Tomcat 6](http://tomcat.apache.org/) to provide the execution environment. A web application can be deployed in Tomcat by one of the following approaches:

- Copy unpacked directory hierarchy into a subdirectory in directory
  $CATALINA_BASE/webapps/. Tomcat will assign a context path to your
  application based on the subdirectory name you choose. We will use
  this technique in the build.xml file that we construct, because it is
  the quickest and easiest approach during development. Be sure to
  restart Tomcat after installing or updating your application.
- Copy the web application archive file into directory
  $CATALINA_BASE/webapps/. When Tomcat is started, it will
  automatically expand the web application archive file into its
  unpacked form, and execute the application that way. This approach
  would typically be used to install an additional application,
  provided by a third party vendor or by your internal development
  staff, into an existing Tomcat installation. NOTE - If you use this
  approach, and wish to update your application later, you must both
  replace the web application archive file AND delete the expanded
  directory that Tomcat created, and then restart Tomcat, in order to
  reflect your changes.

> The description below uses the variable name $CATALINA_BASE to refer
>   the base directory against which most relative paths are resolved. If
>   you have not configured Tomcat 6 for multiple instances by setting a
>   CATALINA_BASE directory, then $CATALINA_BASE will be set to the value
>   of $CATALINA_HOME, the directory into which you have installed Tomcat.

**You can visit this youtube [link](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=deploy%20java%20web%20application&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&ved=0CEAQuAIwAw&url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xIbQ0ONU9uM&ei=-KvvUaO_D4nQrQe1x4GwBQ&usg=AFQjCNGCph1kfsP9c9rkxpbt4LxdZbft9g&bvm=bv.49641647,d.dmg) for video tutorial.**