# Omitting war file name in URL in apache tomcat

Tags: tomcat, war

I don't want war file name in URL in apache tomcat meaning when I open http://:
then my application should be loaded. What config changes should I do for this .I know context path has to be changed in server.xml, but how to do this I don't know.

Comment: see my answer in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17831067/run-java-application/17831289#17831289

Comment: This link also may help you. http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo#How_do_I_make_my_web_application_be_the_Tomcat_default_application.3F